# No domain in LAN but IPScanner shows .localdomain

Tags: networking, dns, lan

I have a LAN that sometimes is giving me problems. When I try to connect to other computers on the same LAN it goes outside my LAN and cannot find them by name. It can find them by IP address directly.  There is no domain controller. This is probably a DNS issue, but I don't think I am versed enough in DNS to understand it.
My computer name shows up on Advanced IP Scanner as *computername*.localdomain
Is that correct?

EDIT: Found the issue that seemed to be causing most of my headaches. One of the VOIP phones was plugged in via the PoE cable it was supposed to be, then its passthrough was plugged into a switch on the network.  This caused some interesting loopback issues but just removing that from the network has seemed to clear up everything.

Comment: Is this a home network? If you only have a few machines that you connect to via computername and you use the same computer to connect from, then you may be able to make good use of the `hosts` file. This file allows for entries on the local machine to resolve IPs to names internally, without a DNS server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is not a home network. Editing the host file does work, but it definitely seems like the incorrect fix. As I continue to trouble shoot I am thinking I might need to open a new topic.  I basically have 192.168.0.1 is firewall - 192.168.0.2 is managed switch - 192.168.0.3 is voip PoE switch.  On 192.168.0.2, two ports are tagged for vlan for the phones on the other switch. Logged into the 192.168.0.2 switch I am unable to ping the 192.168.0.3 ip.

Comment: Yes. Loopback causes trouble in any network, home or enterprise. Post that as an answer and you'll be able to mark it as such and then we'll have a record that this has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue that seemed to be causing most of my headaches. One of the VOIP phones was plugged in via the PoE cable it was supposed to be, then its passthrough was plugged into a switch on the network. This caused some interesting loopback issues but just removing that from the network has seemed to clear up everything.